# Consecutive Day Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table of contactIDs and datetimes, the time being when a letter was generated for the contact. Each contact can only have one letter generated a day. I want to write a query to select any contact that has had letters generated on more than one consecutive day.

I guess I'd need to increment the datetime as records are found but how would I do this separately for each contact?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Nope, contact will never have more than one letter a day. It is unusual for a contact to get a letter the day after getting one. These are who I'm looking for.

Comment: Exactly, and I'm not looking for cases where someone received two in the one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select contactid from ContactTable a inner join Contacttable B on a.contctid=b.contactid and datediff(day,a.date,b.date)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to utilise a calendar table. Use your favourite search engine to find a script to create a calendar table.

Alternatively, [here's one I made earlier](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql)

So here's the query I have rolled with in full, I will explain the detail of it afterwards

```
DECLARE @your_table table (
   contact_id int
 , created_on datetime
);

INSERT INTO @your_table (contact_id, created_on)
          SELECT 9, '2014-01-02 06:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 9, '2014-01-02 18:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 9, '2014-01-05 08:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 9, '2014-01-07 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2014-01-02 00:01'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2014-01-03 23:59' -- Over 24 hours but a "day" different
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-04 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-06 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-08 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-09 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-10 01:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '2014-01-11 01:00'
;

; WITH x AS (
  SELECT your_table.contact_id
       , your_table.created_on
       , calendar.the_date
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY your_table.contact_id ORDER BY calendar.the_date) As sequence
  FROM   @your_table As your_table
   INNER
    JOIN dbo.calendar
      ON your_table.created_on >= calendar.the_date
     AND your_table.created_on <  DateAdd(dd, 1, calendar.the_date)
)
, y AS (
  SELECT curr.contact_id
       , curr.created_on
       , curr.the_date As the_date
       , prev.the_date As previous_date
       , DateDiff(dd, prev.the_date, curr.the_date) As difference_in_days
  FROM   x As curr
   LEFT
    JOIN x As prev
      ON curr.contact_id = prev.contact_id
     AND curr.sequence   = prev.sequence + 1
)
SELECT contact_id
     , created_on
     , the_date
     , previous_date
     , difference_in_days
FROM   y
WHERE  difference_in_days = 1
```

Because you didn't provide any sample data that's where I had to start, so the query is self-contained using a table variable (`@your_table`) as its source.

Once populated we start out with a couple of Common-Table Expressions (CTE for short). Read up here if you're not familiar with the concept: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx . There's not a lot of difference between these and subqueries.

Our first CTE (`x`) joins `@your_table` to the `calendar` table. It does this by returning the single row from the calendar on which the `created_on` date lies, by checking that it is greater than (or equal to) the calendar date and less than the next calendar date (`DateAdd()`).

Once complete we use the windowed function - `Row_Number()` to provide some sequencing.

We partition (i.e. reset the sequence) for each `contact_id` and sort the sequence by the `created_on` date.

Moving on to the second CTE (`y`): we perform a self-join on CTE `x` joining each contact record with its "previous" based on the sequencing.

This allows us to work out the difference in days (`DateDiff()`) between the current and the previous records.

Finally we reduce our resultset to only those records where the difference in days is 1 i.e. **contacts on consecutive days**